# Android device monitor doesn't show any processes

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, adb, android-device-monitor

I don't see any processes in the Android Device Monitor when I tap on a application in my device. Everything is grayed out in the toolbar, what can it be?

USB debugging on device is on.
I tried

```
 adb kill-server
 adb start-server
```

but with no success.

`adb devices` show me the device
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the device and enable the debug mode.

Comment: where to enable?

Comment: Device configuration -> development -> USB  debugging

Comment: USB debugging is on